# Gradle build failed while setting up zookeeper server

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I was trying to setup zookeeper server, I received `Classpath is empty. Please build project first eg. by running gradlew jarAll`.
I ran **>gradle** first but it failed to build. Why is it failing to build ?

Comment: Please add your build.gradle file in this question.

Comment: @Richard, I was using Kafka source which is why I was getting the above error. Now I used Kafka binary and there was no error regarding gradle which solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you need to build anything at all. Don't clone Kafka source. Download from the website.

- https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperStarted.html
- https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart (includes Zookeeper)

Comment: Hi, this works, I was initially using Kafka source but now I downloaded binary. It is not giving any error. Thanks a lot